# How to Forward Using a Button from One Page with Data, Then Access that Data in Another Page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am looking for some simple ways to forward using a button from one page with data to another one. I learned that Redux(haven't studied yet) can be used in storing data when in one page then access it when in another. But it may be overkill because I just need one or two string(s)/number(s). Do you have any idea? Or is Redux the only way?

**PageOne.js**

```
processDataOnPageTwo() {
  /* code here:
   * forward to /PageTwo
   *   with 'data' from this page
   */
}

...
<button onClick={this.processDataOnPageTwo()}>Modify</button>
...
```

**PageTwo.js**

```
processData() {
  /* code here:
   * probably check this.props.data (if applicable) then use it the calculation needed
   */
}
```

Comment: You can pass the data in **props** to PageTwo. <PageTwo handleDataFromPageOne = {dataFromPageOne} />

Comment: Thank you @KRISHNAPATEL . My understanding is, that can be done when you render a component. But how about after a button is clicked?

Comment: You would be able to render the component conditionally. What you can try here is that update the state on button click and render PageTwo conditionally.

Comment: Use the common parent to store some state, use setState when click happens in the PageOne and PageTwo component can use this state at common parent by passing them as props.

Comment: Wow, I'll take note of those solutions. Thank you very much.

Comment: I got excited (newbie :)). While processing the suggested solutions, I realized that they were all about parent child components. So the data don't leave the domain.tld/PageOne. I wish to pass the data to domain.tld/PageTwo.